# NSDatePicker:Get selected date range

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a NSDatePicker control configured to select a date range in the graphical view. I can get the selected date using `datePicker.dateValue` but the question is if a range is selected, How can I access it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `NSDatePicker` is in the NSRangeDateMode, the length of the selected date range is given by [`-[NSDatePicker timeInterval]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDatePickerCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDatePickerCell/timeInterval).